# Display content after creation and loading of all elements in ANGULARJS / IONIC FRAMEWORK

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework for creating apps. In my current project, i am calling many different API in one particular page. ion-content elements should be hidden by default(it should show ion-content when all elements are created into DOM )  Someone help me with this as i don't know how to hide and show all element inside ion-content.

Comment: Seems like you could use the ng-if directive to watch data bound to the controller/$scope.

Comment: I believe it isn't wise to hide `ion-content` instead you can show loader until data is loaded.

Comment: @HardikVaghani yeah that's correct. i want to show all elements only if its fully loaded in ion-content. is there any way to do it.